# Angular Material form field appearance padding size

Tags: html, css, angular-material

On

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
```

Is it possible to reduce the default padding size of the border?

In the developer tool I can find the class and able to reduce size.

[image]

Putting this class in my css would not change the size.

Not sure how to put class name in my css to change the padding.

Answer (score 6):

To reduce the field padding I had to override the appearance-outline and the infix classes like this :

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0.7em 0 0.7em 0 !important;
  top: -0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this class from styles.css

```
div.mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0em 0 !important
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try ng-deep in your component's scss

```
::ng-deep  .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 0em 0;
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 0):

You can try `padding: 0em 0 !important`

Answer (score 0):

Rather get rid of placeholder for mat-label itself when it's not present by adding this to your root.css

```
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-has-label){
  .mat-form-field-infix {
    border-top: 0 !important;
  }
}
```